# Ansible provide ansible_ssh_pass value from an API

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx

At present I provide ssh user and password at inventory level.

[image]

And provide the values from a variable file and vault file.

```
playbook_sample
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - ./vars/obdp-ml-password.yml
    - ./vars/vars.yml
  gather_facts: no
  no_log: true
  tasks:
     - .....some tasks......
```

This makes me keep vault file in GitHub repo. which is ugly. I now have a system where I can fetch password from a REST API. This is the sample output in json for my rest call.

```
{
  "request_id": "xxxx-xxxx",
  "lease_id": "",
  "renewable": false,
  "lease_duration": 0,
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "user": "user_name",
      "password": "some_secret_password"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "created_time": "2020-06-17T11:01:58.496877095Z",
      "deletion_time": "",
      "destroyed": false,
      "version": 1
    }
  },
  "wrap_info": null,
  "warnings": null,
  "auth": null
}.
```

How can I now override ansible_ssh_user and ansible_ssh_password values so that ansible logins to all hosts using credentials obtained from the json output. Whats the proper way this ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to write a [lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins) that will fetch the username and password from your custom API service.

Since you did not say anything about your particular API and if it is an already known service you installed, you might be lucky and find an [existing one](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#plugin-list) that suits your needs.